# Click on div, get caret, replace div with same content and contenteditable=true, then put caret selection on clicked place

Tags: javascript, selection, contenteditable, svelte, caret

I trying to substitute div with contenteditable=true copy, then focus on the second div in a single click.

```svelte
<script>
    let focused = false;
</script>

{#if !focused}
    <div on:click={async () => {
    focused=true;
    }}>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa unde aut eaque optio, dolorem veniam inventore adipisci eius voluptatem, dignissimos exercitationem impedit quibusdam enim illum numquam beatae, doloremque at obcaecati?
    </div>
{:else}
    <div contenteditable={true} on:blur={()=>{
    focused = false;
    }}>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa unde aut eaque optio, dolorem veniam inventore adipisci eius voluptatem, dignissimos exercitationem impedit quibusdam enim illum numquam beatae, doloremque at obcaecati?
    </div>
{/if}
```

https://svelte.dev/repl/abc9dccc9fae46b894d44dde46f34bcf?version=3.38.2

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre]. The code relevant to your problem belongs _directly_ inside your question (in text form & properly formatted; or as a Stack Snippet, in cases where that makes sense), and not just dumped onto an external platform.

Comment: @CBroe howbowdah

Comment: You would have to calculate the position of caret manually from a click. Just have it be content editable all the time...

Comment: @Akxe the problem is that `window.getSelection()` returns range object with destroyed nodes inside :\

Comment: In your position, I would make the div `contentediable` all the time. What is the benefit of having it toggeable?

Comment: @Akxe first div contains Quill server-side rendered HTML, onFocus I dynamically load Quill.js and instantiate it. This is the way to avoid loading the whole library until user starts interact with it

Comment: How about have it only content editable without the Quill and instantiate Quill on focus while looking where is caret and then, if needed, restoring caret position! :)

Comment: @Akxe working snippet in the answer. So user can see server-side rendered HTML, then if he will decide to edit it - quill.js will be loaded and caret will be in the right place. A user won't notice the replacement.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve it by using this function

```
  function getCaretIndex(element) {
    let position = 0;
    const isSupported = typeof window.getSelection !== "undefined";
    if (isSupported) {
      const selection = window.getSelection();
      if (selection.rangeCount !== 0) {
        const range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
        const preCaretRange = range.cloneRange();
        preCaretRange.selectNodeContents(element);
        preCaretRange.setEnd(range.endContainer, range.endOffset);
        position = preCaretRange.toString().length;
      }
    }
    return position;
  }
```